# This operation cannot be executed: The subtangle has not been updated yet

Tags: iota-network, pow, tip-selection, subtangles, python

When I try to send the hello message to tangle, it is returning this error message. I have 2 neighbour nodes and POW enabled in the nodes.

Comment: Do the neighbours know you and send you transactions? Did you wait until your node is in synch with your neighbours?

Comment: I have set up a private tangle with 1 compass and 5 IRI nodes. I try to send data to one of the nodes using the python examples script. That is when I get the below error:BadApiResponse: 400 response from node: This operation cannot be executed: The subtangle has not been updated yet

Comment: So I would check if your nodes are receiving the milestones by Compass, the latest solid subtangle milestone has to be the same value as the last milestone issued by Compass. If they are not, your neighbors are not correctly connected.

Comment: Both the values are the same